# Python ftp download and archive

Tags: python, ftp

I have been trying to script a code with python to grade the main directory of that ftp and archive it into a the local pc. I am not an amateur coder and python is fairly new to me.
What I am getting as an error right now is.

```
File "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\ftp_archiving_script.py", line 24, in <module>
ftpDownload = ftp.retrbinary('RETR', filename)
```

Code:

```
    from ftplib import FTP
import zipfile
import os
try:
    import zlib
    compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
except:
    compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED
modes = { zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED: "deflated",
          zipfile.ZIP_STORED: "stored",
    }

#print "Logging in..."
with FTP('xxx.xxx.xxx') as ftp: #hostname goes here
    ftp.login('xxxx','xxxx') #user followed by pass
    #print "changing to root directory"
    ftp.mlsd('//')
    #print "Accessing files"
    filenames = []
    #print filenames
    ftp.retrlines('NLST', filenames.append)
    try:
        for filename in filenames:
            ftpDownload = ftp.retrbinary('RETR', filename)
            with ZipFile(os.path.join('C:\\','DC_archive.zip'), 'w') as myzip:
                myzip.write(ftpDownload, compress_type=compression)
                myzip.close()
    finally:
        #print "closing"
        ftp.close()
    ftp.quit()
```

Can anyone enlighten me on this problem.

Thank you,

Update

```
try:
    for filename in filenames:
        with io.StringIO() as fObject:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %filename, fObject.write)
            with ZipFile(os.path.join('C:\\','DC_archive.zip'), 'w') as myzip:
                myzip.write(fObject, compress_type=compression)
                myzip.close()
```

updated Traceback for @fals... Also this is using your code below and not the one I have at the top.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\ftp_archive2.py", line 20, in <module>
    ftpDownload = ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, f.write)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 424, in retrbinary
    with self.transfercmd(cmd, rest) as conn:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 386, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 352, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 259, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 233, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 550 File not found
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Python documentation for [ftplib.retrbinary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary):

> FTP.retrbinary(command, callback[, maxblocksize[, rest]])
>
> Retrieve a file in binary transfer mode. command should be an
>   appropriate RETR command: 'RETR filename'. The callback function is
>   called for each block of data received, with a single string argument
>   giving the data block.

Nowhere does it indicate that it returns a file-like object or string.

Instead, you have to create your own callback to write to a file object.

```
with open('my-downloaded-file', 'wb') as f:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, f.write)
```

Here, `f.write` is the callback which will receive data as it arrives from the socket.  If you don't want to save the file to disk using `open`, you can use the [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO) module to simulate a file in memory.

Comment: Thank you I will try fixing it and see what I get

Comment: same error. I'll update the code now. File "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\ftp_archiving_script.py", line 23, in <module>
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %filename, fObject.write)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
import ftplib
from io import BytesIO
import os
import zipfile

REMOTE_HOST = 'xxx.xxx.xxx'
REMOTE_USER = '...'
REMOTE_PASS = '...'
REMOTE_DIR_PATH = '//'
LOCAL_ZIP_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'DC_archive.zip')

ftp = ftplib.FTP(REMOTE_HOST)
try:
    ftp.login(REMOTE_USER, REMOTE_PASS)
    ftp.cwd(REMOTE_DIR_PATH)
    filenames = ftp.nlst()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(LOCAL_ZIP_PATH, 'w') as zf:
        for filename in filenames:
            with BytesIO() as f:
                try:
                    ftpDownload = ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, f.write)
                    zf.writestr(filename, f.getvalue())
                except ftplib.Error as e:
                    print('Skip {}: {}'.format(filename, e))
finally:
    ftp.quit()
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\ftp_archive2.py", line 17, in <module>
    with zipfile.ZipFile(LOCAL_ZIP_PATH, 'w') as zf:
This is the error I get with your code.

Comment: @madmanali93, Show me the full traceback or last line of traceback.

Comment: @madmanali93, I think you posted traceback for AustinPhillips, not for me ;). There's no `... zipfile.ZipFile ....` in the traceback you posted.

Comment: sorry getting people confused now XD ill post the other one now

Comment: @madmanali93, I see. Change the LOCAL_ZIP_PATH to the path where you have write permission. For example, `LOCAL_ZIP_PATH = r'C:\Users\username\DC_archive.zip'`

Comment: @madmanali93, `with zipfile.ZipFile(..) ..` should be out of for loop. Or zip file will be overwritten, and you will get zip file for only one file.

Comment: I am not sure where you want the zipfile to be placed. I am using the exact code you are using. Could you update yours to where you want it.

Comment: @madmanali93, I updated the code. Retry, and if any error occur, please let me know.

Comment: ok updated what the traceback. I am using your code and not mine.

Comment: I added an & between them and it gives me the exact same error

Comment: @madmanali93, I forgot you're using Python 3.3. updated the code.

Comment: ok good update. archive is made but its empty. and I really appreciate your help for working on this for so long.

Comment: sorry it was just me being tired and not adding my host. So im getting a 550 file not found and it skips all the files in there.